# Java Clone Inheritance Example

Tags: java

This clone example confuses me. I don't understand how the first two outputs can be: 111 and 222  instead of: 222 and 222.
Doesn't this "a2 = (A) a1.clone();" line mean that a2 becomes the same as a1?

code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a1 = new A();
    A a2;
    B b1 = new B();
    B b2;

    a2 = (A) a1.clone();
    a2.setI(222);

    // Why the different output?
    System.out.println("a1 = " + a1 + " a1.i " + a1.getI()); // i = 111
    System.out.println("a2 = " + a2 + " a2.i " + a2.getI()); // i = 222

    b2 = (B) b1.clone();

    b2.setI(888); 
    b2.setJ(999); 

    System.out.println("b1 = " + b1 + " b1.i " + b1.getI() + " b1.j " +      b1.getJ());
    System.out.println("b2 = " + b2 + " b2.i " + b2.getI() + " b2.j " + b2.getJ()); 
}
}

public class A implements Cloneable {
    private int i = 111;
    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        try {
            A a = (A) super.clone();
            return a;
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new InternalError();
        }
    }
    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = i;
        }
    }

    public class B extends A {
    private int j = 222;

    @Override
    public Object clone() {  
        Object o = super.clone();               
        B b = (B) o;
        return b;
    }

    public int getJ() {
        return j;
    }

    public void setJ(int j) {
        this.j = j;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values get copied across in a `clone()` operation, but you end up with 2 distinct objects, just that they have the same values.

```
a2 = (A) a1.clone()
```

creates a new object, entirely seperate to a1.  But the internal state of a1 has been replicated into a2.  Therefore, changing a2 has no effect on a1 (if the cloning is done properly!)

Answer (score 2):

No they don't point to same object anymore and hence value change of `a2` doesn't affect the `a1` object. That's the concept of `clone()` you get a same but distinct copy of the object.

When you do this

```
a1=(A)a2.clone();
```

you get a completely new object , independent of the object from which it is copied.

Answer (score 2):

Clone only makes a "shallow" copy of the object, meaning that the primitive values and object references are copied.  What you want (I'm assuming) is a "deep" copy, where referenced objects themselves are cloned.  A few of the most popular ways to do this:

- [Java Deep Cloning Library](https://code.google.com/p/cloning/)
- Serialize the object, and then de-serialize it (warning: this is slow!)
- Implement `clone()` in all of the referenced objects, and call `clone()` on these objects in the referencing object's `clone()` method.  You can also use a copy constructor in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, [`Object.clone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29):

> Creates and returns a copy of this object. The precise meaning of
>   "copy" may depend on the class of the object. The general intent is
>   that, for any object x, the expression:

`x.clone() != x`

> will be true.

Continuing from the same document:

> This method creates a new instance of the class of this object and
>   initializes all its fields with exactly the contents of the
>   corresponding fields of this object, as if by assignment; the contents
>   of the fields are not themselves cloned. Thus, this method performs a
>   "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep copy" operation.

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you provided the sequence of steps are like below.

1. Cloned the object `A` with `i` value as `111` so a cloned object with same value i.e. `111` is created.
2. Then you changed the value of `i` to `222` for the original object so the value of cloned object is not updated as in cloning for primitive types new instances with same value (when the object is cloned) is created.